# why do compiler ask to print two numbers in new line while given newline in arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

Why do arrays as print extra number when given new line in c?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int marks[4];
    int b;
    for(b=0;b<4;b++)
    {
        printf("enter a no for a %d student:\n",b);
        scanf("%d\n",&marks[b]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why do compiler ask two number when I write `'\n'` in `scanf("%d\n",&marks[b]);` and not while i remove new line(`'\n'`) form the code

Comment: Remove the `\n` from the `scanf`. See duplicate post for more explanation.

Comment: I mean in arrays

Comment: What do you mean by "in arrays"? The `\n` is the thing causing the unexpected extra input requirement. Read the duplicate post.